Disable interactivity for core navigation
I want to disable the default interactivity behavior from the core navigation block. I tried the following:
Load my block variation in the functions.php:
function da_custom_block_variations() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'da-custom-navigation-block',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/navigation/block.js',
        array( 'wp-blocks' ),
        null,
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'da_custom_block_variations' );

Register my variation in my block.js:
wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation(
    'core/navigation',
    {
        name: 'da-navigation',
        title: 'DA Navigation without interactivity support',
        description: 'Navigation without interactivity support',
        isDefault: true,
        supports: {
            interactivity: false,
        },
    }
);

I can use my block variation but when I select to open sub-menus on click, the click behavior still gets applied.
After reading about the variations API it seems that I cannot disable the interactivity.
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-variations/
So how can I disable the default navigation interactivity (aria-expands=true/false) and add my own?

I am a little late, I will show dirty solution here, and later I will try to update it with changing of default block, as you attempted.
Please consider marking this as correct answer, as your solution is not answer to question you asked - "disable the default interactivity behavior from the core navigation block".

Dirty solution:
Remove 'data-wp-interactive' attribute on the block before javascript which processes it starts. Add this to javascript which is enqueued in PHP:

 window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // this will disable all navigation blocks interactivity
    // if only one is targeted, add class to it in admin and target this class
    document.querySelector('.wp-block-navigation').removeAttribute('data-wp-interactive');
 })

EDIT:
data-wp-interactive is part of new interactivity API and by removing this attribute early enough you are in effect disabling interactivity behavior. More info here: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2024/03/04/interactivity-api-dev-note/

Thanks for the code snippet. I checked it and it works. Some more context would have been nice. Nevertheless I found some more documentation about the Interactivity API, where the naming convention is described: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/interactivity-api/api-reference/

After a lot of reading, debugging and testing I did not manage it to modify the default core/navigation block as I wanted. The interactivity API still keeps getting in the way. So my solution was to enable the classic menu and make it a custom dynamic block:
My theme's functions.php:
function my_theme_register_menus()
{
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'primary' => __('Primary Menu', 'my-theme'),
        )
    );
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_register_menus');

My theme navigation block render.php:
<?php

$walker = new Classic_Nav_Walker();

$menu_location = isset( $attributes['menuLocation'] ) ? $attributes['menuLocation'] : 'primary';

wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location'  => $menu_location,
        'walker'          => $walker,
        'container'       => 'nav',
        'container_class' => 'my-theme-navigation',
        'echo'            => true,
    )
);

Edit.js:
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import { useBlockProps } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import ServerSideRender from "@wordpress/server-side-render";
import "./editor.scss";
export default function Edit() {
    return (
        <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
            <ServerSideRender block="my-theme/my-theme-navigation" />
        </div>
    );
}

And some custom behaviour inside the view.js. The downside is that you cannot modify the navigation inside the full site editor.
Hope it helps if anyone searches for a similar solution.
